# Built-in utility type Pick explanation

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Can someone explain how built-in Pick<Type, Keys> works?

We have :

1. Implementation of Pick.

```
type Pick<T,K extends keyof T>={  // (1)
    [P in K]:T[P]                 // (2)
}
```

2. Interface of Todo object

```
interface Todo {
    title: string
    description: string
    completed: boolean
}
```

3. Our object

```
const obj: Pick<Todo,"title">={  // (3)
    title:"Hello",
}
```

I don't know why we extend K in point #1? 
We have the key "title" in point #3 and then "title" `extends keyof Todo` in point #1. 
Therefore in point #2 we have [P in "title"|"description"|"completed"]. 
In that case we can use [P in keyof T] instead, but it doesn't work of cource. 
I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr `[P in K]` allows us to define a union of keys (`K`) which may be a **reduced subset** of the total number of keys in `T`. Because we constrain `K` to be `extends keyof T`, we are also saying that the keys must exist on the source object of type `T`. This then allows us to use it as an index for T (e.g. `T[P]`) in later parts of the code

In the example above, using `Pick<Todo, 'title'>`

- [P in K] = `'title'`
- [P in keyof T] = `'title' | 'description' | 'completed'`

If we didn't have `K`, we would not be able to provide the "arguments" needed and instead would be forced to perform operations on all of the keys in `T`

---

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]: T[P]
}

interface Todo {
  title: string
  description: string
  completed: boolean
}

interface PickedTodo {
  title: string
}
// equivalent to Pick<Todo, 'title'>
```

- `T`: This is our source object type (e.g. `Todo`) from which we will be extracting keys (and their value types) that we are interested in
- `K extends keyof T`: This is the set of keys (**that must be present in the source object type**) we are interested in extracting to and applying to our destination object type (e.g. `PickedTodo`).

  - The beauty of this syntax is that we can specify a list of keys which is a **subset** of the source object type's keys (i.e. doesn't expect all keys).
  - These are all valid unions which satisfy `K extends keyof Todo`

    - `'title'`
    - `'title' | 'description'`
    - `'description' | 'completed'`
    - `'title' | 'description' | 'completed'`
    - etc..
- `[P in K]`: In simple terms this reads as 'For every key (`P`) which exists in the union you provided (`K`), do something'.

  - This is the TypeScript way of enabling us to loop over an objects keys
  - In our example, PickedTodo only has one key `title`, i.e. the value of `K` is the following union: `title`
  - This is different to `keyof Todo` (`keyof T`) which would be the union of all keys on `Todo`, i.e.: `'title' | 'description' | 'completed'`
- `T[P]`: Using `T` as a base, extract the type of the value for each of the keys `P`

  - In our example we have already determined that there is only one key in the union `K`, which is `title`. Therefore we only need to perform this mapping operation once and apply to the destination object.
  - Our destination object receives the key `title` with the associated value of `Todo['title']` (`T[P]`) which as we know is `string`
  - The resulting object is therefore `interface PickedTodo { title: string; }`